# Visually updating the caret size after a change to css font-size of a contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11, contenteditable, caret

I have a `contentEditable div` where the user can type in. The user, using the mousewheel, can change the `font-size` of the `div`.

The issue I'm facing: if the `div` is empty and the user changes the `font-size` the caret size won't change: this behave can cause some confusion about the actual `font-size` being used. As soon as the user starts typing in the caret will adjust to the correct size.

This is the code that changes the `css font-size`:

```
$("#textBox").css("font-size", fontSize);
```

The user opens the application (default font size, caret is correct)

[image]

The user changes the font-size to 100 (the caret size is **not** changing according to the font-size):

[image]

The user starts typing in (the caret finally updates):

[image]

I tried to change the contents of the `div` when the font resize happens in case it's empty, but it's not updating the caret:

```
if (realContent.length == 0) {
  console.log("empty");
  $("#textBox").text(" ")
  $("#textBox").text("")
}
```

How can I "refresh" the div and force an update of the caret size?

Answer (score 1):

After the CSS change, `blur()` the element, and then `focus()` it *after a setTimeout of 0*. (it doesn't work without the setTimeout for some reason)

https://jsfiddle.net/ber8ouu3/5/

```js
var textbox = document.querySelector('#textBox');
textbox.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#textBox").css("font-size", 80);
  textbox.blur();
  setTimeout(function() { textbox.focus(); });
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" id="textBox"></div>
```